# Scale (frequency) invariant cross-correlation

Tags: correlation, similarity

I am looking for cross-correlation of two 'signals' that would be invariant of scale(frequency, or sampling).

To give you example what I mean:

Standard cross-correlation of sin(x) and cos(x) find match after pi/2, because sin and cos are the same functions, just phased.

I am looking for some algorithm (I searched but didnt find anything) that would find perfect correlation between sin(x) and sin(2*x) or sin(x) and cos(2x). Same functions, but different frequency scale (or call it sampling).

**Image instead of words:**

**Case 1** ( search sequence in signal, sequence can be of different scale/sampling )
[image]

**Case 2** (Same curve, different scale)
[image]

Any idea? (I am looking for something very fast as far as computation is concerned)
Thanks